# C++ initializer_list iterator returning wrong value

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a class defined like this:

```
initializer_list<string> choices;
initializer_list<string>::iterator current_choice;
bool has_choices = false;
MenuItem(Position position, string prompt) { this->position = position; this->prompt = prompt; }
MenuItem(Position position, string prompt, initializer_list<string> choices) : MenuItem(position, prompt) {
    this->choices = choices;
    this->current_choice = this->choices.begin();
    this->text = *(this->current_choice);
    this->has_choices = true;
}
```

The current menu item is defined as 
    MenuItem* current_menu_item = &menuItems[menuItemIndex];

When I iterate over the initializer_list in the constructor, the correct values are outputted. But later in the code when I try to switch the values, like so:

```
 if (c == KEY_RIGHT) {
    if (current_menu_item->has_choices)
    {
        if (current_menu_item->current_choice != current_menu_item->choices.end()) {
            current_menu_item->current_choice++;
            current_menu_item->text = *(current_menu_item->current_choice);
        }
    }
}
```

It shows the first value of the initializer_list for the next menu item object, and I press right, then crashes. If the next object is selected, and I press right, it crashes.

The objects are put into a vector like so

```
menuItems.push_back(MenuItem(Position(5, 15), "Religion: ", { "*", "*", "*", "Protestant" }));
menuItems.push_back(MenuItem(Position(30, 5), "Do you smoke? ", { "Yes", "No" }));
```

I've tried debugging at various points throughout the code, but I cannot seem to pinpoint where or why it goes wrong.

---

Nevermind, two people pointed out I should use a regular container instead of an initializer_list. Thanks everybody for their answers. I feel dumb now. All I had to do was change the initializer_list to a vector, without changing any other code. I love C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "Working Draft C++, 2012-11-02"

> **18.9 Initializer lists [support.initlist]**
>   2 An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of objects of type const E. [ Note: A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length would be obvious representations for initializer_list. initializer_list is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 8.5.4. **Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements**. — end note ]

If I copy the initializer list into a `std::vector` for example, it works perfectly. You should define your `choices` as a regular container, not as `std::initializer_list`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct A {
    A(const std::initializer_list<std::string> &args) : v(args) {}
    void dump() {
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }

    std::vector<std::string> v;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A a({"Hello, ", "world!"});
    a.dump();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you increment after (not before) you dereference the iterator?

```
current_menu_item->text = *(current_menu_item->current_choice);
current_menu_item->current_choice++;
```

Otherwise, there is a possibility you are dereferencing the end iterator.

Also, another problem, as pointed out by mfontanini, when you call `MenuItem(Position(5, 15), "Religion: ", { "*", "*", "*", "Protestant" })`, etc. that initializer list **expires** at the end of expression, which means your internal intializer list points to invalid memory (initializer lists only copy over pointers). The solution is to use a standard container like `std::vector`.

Comment: Even though this is true, you should address the fact that OP is storing an `initializer_list` and that's a bad idea. It actually *is* a bad idea considering the way he is calling that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your second constructor copies choices by value. Therefore, `current_choice` as iterator validity depends on liveliness of parameter choices. Parameters like `{ "*", "*", "*", "Protestant" }` are kept in stack therefore if the method which calls `push_back` returns then `choices` might disappear and current_choice as iterator becomes a dangling "pointer".